# Copying User Settings

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

Is there a way to copy every setting of an admin account to another admin account. I am currently using the default administrator account, but since it doesn't show in the welcome screen, I want to switch to a new account. But I don't want to loose all files and settings on  the previous account. Obviously they'll be available in the another account always. But can I just copy them in some few steps?
Will copying and replacing the user folder works?

Answer (score 1):

many ways, but i would prefer to copy the whole profile... 1) logon with your new administrator user and than logoff... 2) logon with a 3rd admin user and copy the 1rst userprofile over the 2nd one (if files are in use of the 2nd one try to restart first) - 3) right click the profile folder of the 2nd one an change the permission and owner settings for all subfolders.
(this procedure does not work >xp, after xp there is a different way)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows XP Migration Wizard (also called Windows Easy Transfer) to save the data and settings of the first account into a file and use the same tool to import it back into the second account.

I only found the article for Windows Vista but the Functionality is the same:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928634/en-us

If it is not part of your Windows XP CD then you can download it from Microsoft here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

to start it just run migwiz.exe